# Calling pure virtual function in constructor gives an error

Tags: c++, oop, class, inheritance, virtual

```
class a //my base class
 {
public:
    a()
    {
        foo();
    }
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};



class b : public a
{
    public:
    void foo()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    b obj; //ERROR:  undefined reference to a::foo()
}
```

Why it gives me error? The pure virtual foo is defined. What do I need to change in my code to make it work? I need pure virtual method from base class be called in its constructor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Calling virtual functions in a constructor is [recognised as a bad thing to do](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html).

> During base class construction of a derived class object, the type of
>   the object is that of the base class. Not only do virtual functions
>   resolve to the base class, but the parts of the language using runtime
>   type information (e.g., dynamic_cast (see Item 27) and typeid) treat
>   the object as a base class type.

So your instantiation of `b` invokes the `a` constructor. That calls `foo()`, but it's the `foo()` on `a` that gets called. And that (of course) is undefined.

Comment: I see. I will change the design.

Comment: would making class a abstract solve the issue?

Comment: @Falaque - I don't believe so. See the linked article by Scott Meyers

Comment: @user1873947 the Class 'a' (see the example in question).

Comment: @BrianAgnew can you or anyone else suggest a better pattern/design?

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from a book "Let Us C++"by Yashwant Kanetkar

> It is always the member function of the current class , is called.That
>   is , the virtual mechanism doesn't work within the constructor

So, the `foo()` of `class a` gets called.
Since it is declared `pure virtual`, it will report an error

Comment: It'll report an error... or compile fine but cause UB, crashing _if you're lucky_. Either way, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` function is called in class `a`'s constructor, and at that time, object `b` has not been fully constructed yet, hence it's `foo` implementation is unavailable.

Quoted from "Effective C++":

> Don't call virtual functions during construction or destruction,
>   because such calls will never go to a more derived class than that of
>   the currently executing constructor or destructor